# Return rows which have the same values in two columns, but different values in another

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
       id  |           name           |      address       | code 
-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------
       101 | joe smith                | 1 long road        | SC1
       102 | joe smith                | 6 long road        | SC1
       103 | amy hughes               | 5 hillside lane    | SC5
       104 | amy hughes               | 5 hillside lane    | SC5
```

I want to return the rows that are duplications based on `name` and `code` but have different `address` fields.

I had something like this originally (which looked for duplications across the `name, address and code` columns:

```
SELECT name, address, code, count(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING count(*) >1;
```

Is there a way I can expand on the above to only return rows that have the same `name` and `code` but different `address` fields?

In my example data above, I would only want to return:

```
       id  |           name           |      address       | code 
-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------
       101 | joe smith                | 1 long road        | SC1
       102 | joe smith                | 6 long road        | SC1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `address` from the select list and `GROUP BY` and use `count(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT name, code, count(DISTINCT address)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name, code
HAVING count(DISTINCT address) > 1;
```